# Search query for multiple tables with count(*)?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search field for an online shop that uses MySQL query for 2 different tables. The first table is *vinyls* which has 13 columns, and the second table is *products* which has 10 columns. The result I want is that if you enter a keyword, it will search the *album_name* and *artist_name* columns of table *vinyls*, and the *name* column in table *products* to find any matches.

My php code first counts the number of times a hit is made, and if it does, uses a query again to display the hits like online stores do. However, when I tested it, it only shows results from the *vinyls* table and not the *products* table. I've tried using *UNION* but because both tables have a different number of columns, it results in an error. I've used *NULL* to fill up the missing columns needed for *union* but it doesn't work too. Joins doesn't help either as the two tables do not have any similar column. What complicated it is the use of count(*) for the first query.

My SQL query using UNION and COUNT:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows 
FROM vinyls 
WHERE (     album_name LIKE :keyword 
        OR  artist_name LIKE :keyword)
      ) 
union 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows 
FROM products 
WHERE name LIKE :keyword)
```

My php code for search field:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("(SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows 
                        FROM vinyls 
                        WHERE (     album_name LIKE :keyword 
                                OR  artist_name LIKE :keyword)
                              ) 
                        union 
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows 
                        FROM products 
                        WHERE name LIKE :keyword)");

$stmt->execute(['keyword' => '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%']);
$row = $stmt->fetch();


if($row['numrows'] < 1){
    echo '<h1 class="page-header">No results found for <i>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</i></h1>';
}else{
    echo '<h1 class="page-header">Search results for <i>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</i></h1>';
    try{
        $inc = 3;   
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("(SELECT * 
                                FROM vinyls 
                                WHERE (     album_name LIKE :keyword 
                                        OR  artist_name LIKE :keyword)
                                    ) 
                                union 
                                (SELECT * 
                                FROM products 
                                WHERE name LIKE :keyword)");

        $stmt->execute(['keyword' => '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%']);

        foreach ($stmt as $row) {...
```

I'm already stumped on how to search the 2 tables from only one search field and display the results from both tables and not only just one table. And it's a similar problem too when adding items to cart as they can be either from the two tables and I have to "join" the two tables again.

Where did I go wrong?

Edit:
Sample data

`Vinyls table
+----+------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| id | album_name       | artist_name               | genre     |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| 11 | Ravel Bolero     | Boston Symphony Orchestra | Classical |
| 12 | TV Calendar Show | Arthur Godfrey            | Orchestra |
| 13 | Flip Phillips    | The Phillips Quartet      | Jazz      |
| 14 | The Modern Idiom | Various artists           | Jazz      |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+-----------+`

Products table
+----+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | category_id | name                                                 |
+----+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 31 |          15 | Tonka/Diecast trucks and cars                        |
| 32 |          21 | Plate Number Georgia PQQ 1151                        |
| 33 |           6 | Walt Disney Read Along Casette Tapes                 |
| 34 |           7 | Herbert Von Karajan                                  |
| 35 |           8 | BANK IT! Board Game                                  |
| 36 |           9 | Iraqi Most Wanted Playing Cards                      |
| 37 |          10 | STAR TREK ( 1991,'92,'93 ) Stamp Oasis Rubber Stamps |
| 38 |          11 | Batman and Friends Action Figure Toys (4" - 5")      |
| 39 |          12 | Delta Dawn Porcelain Doll                            |
+----+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+

Expected result is similar to amazon's search bar, where you type a keyword and results show after you've entered. What I want in my site is that if I type orchestra in the search field, it will display Boston Symphony Orchestra's row. Or if I type cars, it will display the tonka row.

What I get is that it only shows the *vinyls* table and never the *products* table even if I type cars and there should have been a hit in the products table. Or I get an error because union is applicable only to tables with similar number of columns.

Comment: You can pass a field/column name to the COUNT function

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code.

First, your count query should work and throw no error, but you only look at the first result row (the one of your vinyls). But your query returns two rows. (It will return one row with the `numrows` field for the first unioned query (vinyls) and one row with the `numrows` field for the second query (products) in your union.

You could wrap it into a `SUM` to only get one result row back:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(numrows) AS numrows FROM
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows 
                        FROM vinyls 
                        WHERE (     album_name LIKE :keyword 
                                OR  artist_name LIKE :keyword)
                              ) 
                        union 
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows 
                        FROM products 
                        WHERE name LIKE :keyword)) AS sumQuery");
```

The second problem is the query, which loads your result and throws the exception because of the nonmatching column count. You have to define which columns of each of the two unioned queries should be returned, and they have to match on both. So f.e. do this:

```php
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("(SELECT id, album_name AS name, artist_name
                                FROM vinyls 
                                WHERE (     album_name LIKE :keyword 
                                        OR  artist_name LIKE :keyword)
                                    ) 
                                union 
                                (SELECT id, name, NULL AS artist_name
                                FROM products 
                                WHERE name LIKE :keyword)");
```

Comment: I've tried it but it couldn't recognise numrows and throws a 'undefined index: numrows' error in the `if($row['numrows'] < 1)` line. I've also run a query in cmd and it still gives out two rows.

Comment: Updated the query, please try again :)